# Перезаписывается переменная, а не должна

Tags: python, pynput

Мне необходимо отследить нажатия клавиатуры и если подряд будет нужное сочетание букв выполнить определённый код(эта часть работает) и ещё надо отслеживать состояние кода, то есть если первое действие действие не было выполнено(не был набран определённый набор символов) второе действие не выполнялось(защита от ложного срабатывания). Проблема в том что функция on_press не хочет принимать второй аргумент и выпадает в ошибку, а если я пытаюсь инициализироать переменную состояния внутри функции, то она перезаписывается при каждой итерации функции, хотя я попятался установить защиту от этого.
Вот мой код:

```
from pynput import keyboard

mass = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0,']
obraz_m = ["'m'", "'i'", "'c'", "'u'", "'r'", "'i'"]
obraz_naz = ["'g'", "'o'", "'b'", "'a'", "'c'", "'k'"]

#sost = False

def naz(key):
    try:
        sost = sost
    except NameError:
        sost = False
        print('отладочное сообщение')
    mass[0] = mass[1]
    mass[1] = mass[2]
    mass[2] = mass[3]
    mass[3] = mass[4]
    mass[4] = mass[5]
    key = str(key)
    mass[5] = key
    print(mass)
    print(sost)
    if mass == obraz_m and sost == False:
        print('horay')
        sost = True
        print(sost)
    elif mass == obraz_naz and sost == True:
        print('back tak back')
        sost = False
        print(sost)

def otz(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
         return False

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=naz, on_release=otz) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

А если подать второй аргумент, то появляется такая ошибка:

```
Unhandled exception in listener callback      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 162, in inner       
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 280, in _process         
    self.on_press(key)     
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 78, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:       
TypeError: naz() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:/Users/Kirill/Desktop/cmena_oboi/main.py", line 41, in <module>
    listener.join()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 210, in join
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 695, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 162, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 280, in _process
    self.on_press(key)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 78, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
TypeError: naz() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если переменную sost использовать как глобальную в функции? Видимо ты пытался, но из за того, что она была локальной, тебе било ошибку.

```
from pynput import keyboard

mass = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0,']
obraz_m = ["'m'", "'i'", "'c'", "'u'", "'r'", "'i'"]
obraz_naz = ["'g'", "'o'", "'b'", "'a'", "'c'", "'k'"]

sost = False

def naz(key):
    global sost
    mass[0] = mass[1]
    mass[1] = mass[2]
    mass[2] = mass[3]
    mass[3] = mass[4]
    mass[4] = mass[5]
    key = str(key)
    mass[5] = key
    print(mass)
    print(sost)
    if mass == obraz_m and sost == False:
        print('horay')
        sost = True
        print(sost)
    elif mass == obraz_naz and sost == True:
        print('back tak back')
        sost = False
        print(sost)

def otz(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
         return False

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=naz, on_release=otz) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: А вообще код конечно можно сильно улучшить, можешь написать мне в вк - https://vk.com/dimabytes вместе посмотрим

Comment: Спасибо, большое. Помогло. Похоже так и есть, как вы сказали